# Uniqueness existence for a PDE

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve a set of exercises in order to prepare myself for a test. This question verses about energy method on partial differential equations and I would like to ask for help on that, and, if possible, a refference on energy methods and maximum principles. I'm a begginer on partial differential equations.

Show that there is at most one solution to the problem
$$\begin{cases}u_t=\alpha^2u_{xx}+g,\textrm{ in }(0,L)\times(0,\infty)\\
u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0,t\geqslant 0\\
u(x,0)=u_0(x),\textrm{ in }[0,L]\\
u\in C^2([0,L]\times(0,\infty))\cap C([0,L]\times[0,\infty))
\end{cases}$$
if $u$ is a continuous, differentiable by parts, $u_0(0)=u_0(L)=0$, $g\in C((0,L)\times(0,\infty))$, using: (a) the maximum principle; (b) the energy method. Obtain the candidate for a solution, of the form $u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n(t)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$.

Thanks in advance!
P.S.: Oscar Niemeyer lives forever!

Comment: Livessssss  Foooreeeeeeveeerrrrrrrrrrr!!!!!!!!

Comment: Foreverrrr!!!!  :)

Comment: FALSE! Niemeyer is DEAD now.

Comment: It was just a tribute from an admirer, only. But the question of PDE?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The existence is guaranteed by Theorem (Theorem 2, page 50, Evans, L.C. Partial Differential Equations).
Let $ T>0$ arbitrary and suppose $w=u_{1}-u_{2}$. Then 
$$\begin{cases}w_{t}=\alpha^2w_{xx}, \textrm{ in }(0,L)\times(0,T]\\
w(x,0)=0, x\in(0,L)\\
w(x,t)=0, \{0,L\}\times[0,T]
\end{cases}$$ 
By the principle of maximum

max $w$ in$[0,L]\times[0,T]=$max $w$ in $\{0,L\}\cup\{0,T\}=0$.
Then, $w=0$ in $[0,T], \forall T>0\Longrightarrow
u_{1}=u_{2}$.

Item b), I do not know :(

Comment: For b), note that 
$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^L w^2 = \int 2ww_t = \int_0^L 2\alpha^2 ww_{xx} = -2\alpha^2 \int_0^L (w_x)^2 \le 0.$$

Comment: Good morning Sam. First thanks for listening. I understand, this is going to help me in other things. But you used Green's identity, right? This is energy method? thank you

Comment: I don't know if I would call it "Green's identity", the third equality is by integration by parts, using the fact that the boundary terms vanish. I believe this is the energy method, yes. If we define the energy functional by $E[w] = \int_0^L w^2$, then this inequality says that the energy can never increase for solutions of your PDE. So the point is that you want to find some functional $E$, which satisfies $E[w]=0$ iff $w=0$ and such that $E[w]$ is non-increasing for all solutions of the problem at hand. This immediately gives uniqueness.

Comment: So the problem of using the energy method to prove uniqueness basically consists in finding the right energy functional for your problem. At least this is how I interpret it!

Comment: @Sam Why can switch derivative and integral in first equality?